# CartoDB torque chart stop from playing on page load

Tags: carto

Is there a way to use a CartoDB torque chart such that the chart does not automatically play upon page load?

Answer (score 1):

You can stop or pause the Torque jayer, but this requires using CartoDB.js. You can see the example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/iriberri/ca6c9910bb75329e98c2). Copying the code below for the record:

```
 <body>
<div id="map"></div>

<!-- include cartodb.js library -->
<script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/cartodb.js"></script>

<script>
  function main() {

    var torqueLayer;
    cartodb.createVis('map', 'VIZ_JSON_URL', {
        shareable: true,
        title: true,
        description: true,
        search: true,
        tiles_loader: true
    })
    .done(function(vis, layers) {
      //First layer is the basemap, the second is the Torque layer
      torqueLayer = layers[1];
      torqueLayer.pause();
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  window.onload = main;
</script>
```